# Find multiple values that match and return value from another column, in another workbook

Tags: excel, vba, lookup

I'm trying to create a super VLOOKUP function in VBA and I've gotten it to work fine within the same sheet but i can't seem to figure it out for getting it to work across other books.

Basically this function takes three arguments: Lookup Value, Lookup Table and Return Column.

Lookup value is used to match against every cell within the lookup table and when a match is found, it will return the value from the cell in Return Column at the matched cells row.

Here is my code:

```
Function SUPERLOOKUP(lv As Range, lt As Range, rc As Range)
Dim cell As Range
Dim output As String

For Each cell In lt
    If cell.Value = lv Then
        output = output & Range(ColumnLetter(uRC.Column) & cell.Row).Value & ", "
    End If
Next cell

SUPERLOOKUP = Left(output, Len(output) - 2)
End Function
```

ColumnLetter is a function i use to convert the column number to it's letter value.

Any help is appreciated or even to be pointed in the right direction.

Comment: user Return Column, thats what it was previously called (i guess it would be rc instead in that code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this line:

```
output = output & Range(ColumnLetter(uRC.Column) & cell.Row).Value & ", "
```

`Range` will reference the `ActiveSheet`, so you need to qualify it with a worksheet reference.

Eg (switching to `Cells` to avoid having to convert a column number to a letter):

```
output = output & lt.Parent.Cells(cell.row, uRC.Column).Value & ", "
```

or

```
output = output & cell.EntireRow.Cells(uRC.Column).Value & ", "
```